# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in basic login system

Tags: php

I´m trying to do a login form with php but I´m having an issue that I´m not finding where is the error.

When I submit the form with the correct data I´m having this erros:

**Error one:**

-> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() :

```
`foreach($query as $autUser);`
```

**Error two:**

-> Notice: Undefined variable: autUser here

```
if($autEmail == $autUser['email'] && $autSenha == $autUser['senha'])
```

And also gives me the error 'Wrong Pass' and I put the correct answer.

Somebody there have exprience with this errors?

Can you see some error?

**My php:**

```
      <?php if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
        {
            $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

            if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email']))  
            {
              echo 'Email empty or invalid';
            }

            else if(strlen($f['pass']) <8 || strlen($f['pass'])>12)
            {
                echo 'Pass must have between 8 and 12 chars!';
            }

            else
            {
                $autEmail = $f['email'];
                $autpass = $f['pass'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users where email= '$autEmail'";
                $exeqr = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            if($query)
            {
                foreach($query as $autUser);
                if($autEmail == $autUser['email'] && $pass == $autUser['pass'])
                {
                    echo 'Login Sucess';
                }

                else
                {
                    echo ' Wrong Pass';
                }


            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Informed email does not exist';
            }

            }
        }   


?>
```

**My html:**

```
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
    <label>
        <span>E-mail:</span>
        <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($f['email'])) echo $f['email']; ?>" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input type="password" class="radius" name="pass" value="<?php if(isset($f['pass'])) echo $f['pass']; ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are rewriting ``$autEmail`` with password after assigning email.

``$autEmail = $f['email']; $autEmail = $f['pass'];`` And thus it can't find email that equals password in database. Also in login success loop theres undefined constant (probably you wanted ``$autpass`` variable there)

Comment: Thank your for your tips.. but now I´m getting different and worst error!

Comment: Well, I solve it using mysql_fectch_assoc($exeqr) instead of the foreach loop. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

- Don't use mysql - use mysqli or PDO instead
- echo out/dump $autEmail variable and see what it holds
- copy the query and test it with no PHP code (via phpMyAdmin for example or command line sql)

Try changing the comparison used to `if(mysql_num_rows($exeqr) === 0)`

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know yet how to use PDO or mysqli, and your if condition dont solve my problem... But I change some things and now I´m having now a different problem, its entering in my if condition when the pass is wrong and says that "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()!"

Comment: Well, I solve it using mysql_fectch_assoc($exeqr) instead of the foreach loop. Thank you for your tips! By the way, Can I develop this login system with normal php and mysql, and then change only the sql statements to pdo, and the logic of my login system stays the same? Or change to pdo when we have already done with normal php/mysql the logic will be also different 
and not only the sql statements?